# Generate and display unqiue PDF filename

Tags: php

I am using FPDF to convert php form into a PDF. I have it working perfectly but stuck on one bit and wondering if someone can please give me some guidance.

I have it creating the PDF and saving the PDF to the server. But I have it using the same filename, so it it always overrides itself each time it is generated. I need it to create and then display the filename with a unique filename to the user

E.G. template1.pdf, template2.pdf, template3.pdf etc

Ideally as well as displaying the PDF, prompting the user to download it.

I have tried

```
$file1 = 'template'."_DOC_".md5(rand(0,999);
```

But don't know how to ensure the right file then gets displayed to the user in header code.

```
$filename="template.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
header("Location: template.pdf");
```

Filename stays the say so overrides each time

Comment: `$pdf->Output($file1,'F'); header("Location: ".$file1);` …? (A `Location` header should rather contain at least the path from the domain root, if you specify a file name only and this is not happening in the root directory of the website, I would not rely on every client interpreting this correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php)() function to create a unique name.

The alternative would be to create a database and store the data there. Via Auto_Increment you would get a unique ID with which you can create a name for the PDF file.

These are in principle the most common options. You could also, if you have a username, combine it with a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the file md5 as the pdf name.

```
$filename="template.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
$pdf_name = mdf_file($file_name).".pdf"
rename($file_name,$pdf_name);
header("Location: $pdf_name");
```